# Using existing database without moving the file

Tags: expo, expo-sqlite

using expo sqlite, I want to use my existing db that exists in assets folder without trying to move/copy the file to files folder. is that possible?

here is the code that expo uses

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';

async function openDatabase(pathToDatabaseFile: string): Promise<SQLite.WebSQLDatabase> {
  if (!(await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite')).exists) {
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite');
  }
  await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
    Asset.fromModule(require(pathToDatabaseFile)).uri,
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite/myDatabaseName.db'
  );
  return SQLite.openDatabase('myDatabaseName.db');
}
```